# What is the use of R.Drawable.Loader in android app while downloading image from URL

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-emulator

This might be a silly question, but i am stuck at a single place from quite some time and am not able to figure out the reason.

I am trying to download image from a URL to an android app. For this I am following this tutorial - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

The problem is that eclipse (I am doing coding in eclipse) is giving the error: *Loader cannot be resolved or is not a field* on the line where i have wriiten *int load = R.drawable.loader*

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: because you dont have an image named loader in your drawable folder

Comment: Ok. But what is the use of this image ? And how to choose such image and add it to the drawable folder ? (I am new to Android Programming)

Comment: just copy an image and paste it

Comment: tutorial says "loader image, will be shown before loading image". So it is the real image not yet loaded placeholder image thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the information given in the tutorial you linked to, R.drawable.loader is a place holder image used by the tutorial app to show to the user before the real image has finished downloading.

If the tutorial site allows you to download full projects, you can probably find this image in the `/res/drawable(-something)/` directory. If not, you can pick any random placeholder image you like, rename it to loader. and put it in one of the `res/drawable` folders.